# Python setuptools - clean doesn't work

Tags: python, setuptools

I created a python package using setup tools, and it installs fine, but when I try to clean (using verbose mode) the following message shows and **nothing is cleaned (the build and dist directories are NOT removed)**:

```
running clean
'build/temp.linux-i686-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
```

The contents of the build package are the following:

```
bdist.linux-i686  lib.linux-i686-2.7
```

So my question is, why doesn't this temp.linux-i686-2.7 folder exist? Should it? Why does clean think it should be there?

By the way, my setup.py file is very simple, I just copied supervisord's file (https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/setup.py) and modified just the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'build/temp.linux-i686-2.7' is one of the normal place for .py and .so files to be stored if you do:

```
python setup.py build
```

THat is probably why it try to cleans it, just to be sure. Without verbose you don't get that warning.

Comment: But it doesn't clean anything. So it seems it isn't just a warning, but an error message. I just wanted to do a install and then a clean, and with the install command that directory isn't created.

Comment: I just tried to use the build command, and 'build/temp.linux-i686-2.7' wasn't created, just the 'build/lib.linux-i686-2.7' directory...

Comment: Then that depends on setup file? I get the build/temp... with same content as build/lib... . Maybe yours does not create a .so?

Comment: No, it doesn't create an .so. Is this build/temp created only if you do? So why does clean always try to clean it?

Comment: I just reread the clean command description: "clean up temporary files from 'build' command". So those other dirs (build/bdist.linux-i686, build/lib.linux-i686-2.7 and others) aren't considered temporary? You can't clean those with setuptools?

Comment: `python setup.py clean` does clean the `build/temp.linux-i686-2.7` but not the `build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7`. So the first is temporary. It does not reappear if you do `python setup.py build` after that (because the result is built).

Comment: @felipou: please edit the information required into the answer, or ask Gerard to do so. Comments are liable to get deleted, never refer to them from within a Q or an A.

Comment: Thank you Mat for editing. I was travelling and offline for a few days.